# Row-wise shifting pivoted data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need following data

```
ID  1            2            3            4            5
--- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -----------
1   NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         Level 1
2   NULL         NULL         NULL         Level 1      Level 2
3   NULL         NULL         Level 1      Level 2      Level 3
4   NULL         Level 1      Level 2      Level 3      Level 4
5   Level 1      Level 2      Level 3      Level 4      Level 5
```

to be transformed as:

```
ID  Level1       Level2       Level3       Level4       Level5
--- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
1   Level 1      NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL
2   Level 1      Level 2      NULL         NULL         NULL
3   Level 1      Level 2      Level 3      NULL         NULL
4   Level 1      Level 2      Level 3      Level 4      NULL
5   Level 1      Level 2      Level 3      Level 4      Level 5
```

i.e. in every row data of columns `1,2,3,4,5` is shifted to the left by a number of positions necessary to place first non-null value among them to first position.

Data is originated from self-referencing table:

```
create table data (ID int not NULL, ParentID int, Name varchar(50))
```

by applying following statement (which is wrapped to a table-valued function) to a subset of records from this table:

```
with Path(ID, ParentID, Name, Level)
as
(
    select ID, ParentID, Name, 0 from data where ID = @id
    union all
    select d.ID, d.ParentID, d.Name, p.Level-1
    from data d
        join Path p on p.ParentID = d.ID
)
select
    [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
from
    (select 5 + Level as Level, Name from Path) s
    pivot (max(Name) for Level in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) p
```

Currently this transform is realized with a bunch of `case` operators after data is pivoted. But I feel that perhaps there should be something that can be done before pivoting (to make it more elegant and/or effective).

Ideally I would like to see here as much various approaches for solving this task as possible (any changes before or after pivoting, not matter).

Number of levels is known and constant (and equals 5 in this case).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f58c9/1) sample

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Fiddle is very useful.  I got what you wanted by changing the function.  Here is the revised function:

```
create function ftInfo_new(@id int)
returns table as
return
    with Path(ID, ParentID, Name, Level) as
          (select ID, ParentID, Name, 0
           from data
           where ID = @id
           union all
           select d.ID, d.ParentID, d.Name, p.Level-1
           from data d join
                Path p
                on p.ParentID = d.ID
         )
    select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
    from (select 1 - Level as Level, Name
          from Path
         ) s
        pivot (max(Name) for Level in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]));
```

You can also do it by *increasing* the levels instead of decreasing them:

```
create function ftInfo_new(@id int)
returns table as
return
    with Path(ID, ParentID, Name, Level)
    as
    (
        select ID, ParentID, Name, 1
        from data
        where ID = @id
        union all
        select d.ID, d.ParentID, d.Name, p.Level+1
        from data d join
             Path p
             on p.ParentID = d.ID
    )
    select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
    from (select Level as Level, Name
          from Path
         ) s
        pivot (max(Name) for Level in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) p
```

Comment: Gordon, in the original data let's take a row with `ID=4`, then let's take transformed row with the same ID. Note that data in columns `[1]` to `[5]` should go as 'Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level4', NULL. In your variants it is not only shifted, but also gets mirrored ('Level 4', 'Level 3', 'Level 2' 'Level1', NULL).